# Authenticate user from Marklogic..Marklogic as Login server

Tags: authentication, ldap, marklogic

I want to authenticate user using MarkLogic. We are trying to use MarkLogic as Login Server , means I want to check user present in MarkLogic with his role and display appropriate page.

Using JavaScript and node.js.

Please provide code as I am new to MarkLogic.

We have configured LDAP with MarkLogic.

---

When I enter user credentials in login-form, it will verify against MarkLogic and redirect to appropriate page based upon role defined in MarkLogic?

Can anyone explain with simple example code?

Answer (score 3):

LDAP is used by MarkLogic to authenticate MarkLogic logins using an external LDAP server, not to provide LDAP services for authentication by other applications.

You can use MarkLogic as a 'Login Server' to the extent that you can provide a HTTP interface which authenticates the user, but your 'client' application will need to enforce this.  Depending on what authentication protocol you use will dictate how to do it.

You can use the REST or HTTP API.

Simple example, using "Basic Digest" authentication would require to create an HTTP Application on MarkLogic using a simple "index.html" file which can contain any static content such as "OK". Then, do the following:

- Create users in MarkLogic
- Set the HTTP Application to use "Basic Digest"
- Any user or application connecting to that port will either get an "OK" result or an Unauthorized HTTP error.

It will then be up to your node.js application to determine how to proceed.